# Knockout js checkbox list based on Dropdown list showing by default checked, it should be unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

If i am changing the dropdown value for the binding of the checkbox list in knockout it showing me default checked, i want to display unchecked..

On Page Load Checkbox list working fine.. but when dropdown / select value changed the child checkboxlist showing checked.. i want to display uncheck..

also after change event of select box if i am check the check all checkbox - showing me boolean is not a function error
//HTML

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: allSelect" />
    All
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Locations">
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected">
        </td>

        <td>
            <p data-bind="text: Name"></p>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
</p>
```

//checkbox all

```
var locations = model.Locations;

var Location = function (location)
{
    var self = this;
    self.Id = location.Id;
    self.Name = location.Name;

    self.IsSelected = ko.observable(location.IsSelected);
    console.debug("kp1 : " + location.IsSelected);
};

var mappedLocations = [];

ko.utils.arrayForEach(locations, function (location) {
    mappedLocations.push(new Location(location));
});

console.debug(mappedLocations);

self.Locations = ko.observableArray(mappedLocations);

self.allSelect = ko.computed({

    read: function () {
        var allSelected = true;
        self.selectedIds = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Locations(), function (item)
        {
            console.debug("kp : " + item.IsSelected());
            if (!item.IsSelected())
            {

                allSelected = false;

            }
            else
            {

                self.selectedIds.push(item.Id);
            }

        });
        console.debug('selectedIds: ' + self.selectedIds);

        return allSelected; //to trigger the browser default bahaviour
    },
    write: function (value)
    {


        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Locations(), function (item)
        {

            item.IsSelected(value);
        });
    }

});
```

//Dropdown

```
self.changeProject = function ()
{
    console.debug('Change Project ' + self.ModelingProjectId());
    self.Locations.removeAll();

    var data = { id: self.ModelingProjectId() };
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: root + 'Location/LocationsByProjectandParentId',
        data: data
    }).done(function (json, textStatus, jqXHR) { //see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
        {

            self.Locations.push(new Location(json[i]));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ARe you invoking changeProject on dropdown change?. You might be updating the isSelected to true in the action and returning the result. As you are using the same Locations observable for your checkbox also you might be getting checkbox checked.

Comment: Yes, right change project is dropdown change event... when i am binding locatins with json resonse what i have to do extra things.. to make workable checkbox list during page_load.. here issue is that page load time checkboxes list check / uncheck work fine...but when i am change the dropdwon and bind checkboxes then all child checkboxes showing checked instead of unchecked, what i have to do for exrathings.. can you update the code or can reate jsfiddle

Comment: Just curious to know the things that you are doing when you go to url 'Location/LocationsByProjectandParentId'

Comment: Yes, what about checkbox check all not working, do you have any idea?

Comment: It would be easy to say what's happening to the checkbox check until you say what you are doing in your url..

Comment: In dropdown change event, i am binding checkbox list, you can check the code or you can R & D for bind checkbox list in dropdown change event.

Comment: oh!!! you say I need to do the R & D homework for you :O

Comment: if you would like then only other wise leave it..

Comment: ok then.. Anywayz.. sorry for disturbing you